# How to pass string to 'ranges' parameter in spreadsheets.values.batchGet() google sheets api

Tags: python, google-sheets

Making a request to the spreadsheets API via .get(), for a single range, works as follows:

```
roster_import = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=<SPREADSHEET ID>, ranges='<sheet name>!A1:A20', majorDimension='ROWS')
```

However, I want to get more than one range at a time due to the data I want being out of order. In the documentation found [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet) and [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/reading), they both state:

> Read multiple ranges The following spreadsheets.values.batchGet
>   request reads values from the ranges Sheet1!B:B, and Sheet1!D:D. The
>   ValueRenderOption UNFORMATTED_VALUE setting indicates that values will
>   be calculated, but not formatted in the response. Empty trailing rows
>   and columns are omitted from the response.
>
> The request protocol is shown below. The Reading and Writing Values
>   guide shows how to implement reads in different languages using the
>   Google API client libraries.
>
> GET
>   https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheetId/values:batchGet?
>               ranges=Sheet1!B:B&ranges=Sheet1!D:D&valueRenderOption=UNFORMATTED_VALUES?majorDimension=COLUMNS
>
> The response consists of an object with the spreadsheet ID and an
>   array of ValueRange objects corresponding to each requested range,
>   listed in the order they were requested. For example:
>
> {   "spreadsheetId": spreadsheetId,   "valueRanges": [
>       {
>         "range": "Sheet1!B1:B1000",
>         "majorDimension": "COLUMNS",
>         "values": [
>           ["Cost",20.5,15,100,135.5]
>         ]
>       },
>       {
>         "range": "Sheet1!D1:D1000",
>         "majorDimension": "COLUMNS",
>         "values": [
>           ["Ship Date",42430,42444,42449,42449]
>         ]
>       }   ] }

and

> Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet Returns one or more ranges of
>   values from a spreadsheet. The caller must specify the spreadsheet ID
>   and one or more ranges.
>
> HTTP request GET
>   https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values:batchGet
>
> The URL uses gRPC Transcoding syntax.
>
> Parameters
>
> spreadsheetId - string - The ID of the spreadsheet to retrieve data from.
>
> ranges - string - The A1 notation of the values to retrieve.

Neither of which tell me how to format the string when passing into the spreadsheets().values().batchGet()

I have tried the following:

- ranges='!A1:A2!D1:D2'
- ranges='!A1:A2&!D1:D2'
- ranges='!A1:A2', ranges='!D1:D2'
- ranges='!A1:A2D1:D2'
- ranges='!A1:A2&D1:D2'

How do I format the string to query multiple ranges?

Thank you

BitShift

Comment: Could you please add the solution you found as an actual answer rather than as an edit? It would improve the readability for other community members that are facing the same issue as you did

Comment: Yeh sure, I didn't make it an answer as I wasn't sure about ettiquette and I've been scolded before when doing that. Updating now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer found [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#reading)

to quote:

```
range_names = [
    # Range names ...
]
result = service.spreadsheets().values().batchGet(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, ranges=range_names).execute()
ranges = result.get('valueRanges', [])
print('{0} ranges retrieved.'.format(len(ranges)))
```

The necessary value is an array of strings, each string must contain the following

```
<sheet_name>!<start_range>:<end_range>
```

Comment: what if I don't know the sheet_name. In other words, I want to know the total sheet_names in a spreadsheet.

Comment: @kartiktyagi you can use the getName() method on a sheet, target_sheet.getName(), or you can get the list of sheets in a spreadsheet with .getSheets(), then loop on the resulting array of sheets and get their names.